# excel error: you have entered too few arguments

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use vlookup on 6 workbooks to get data's in my final workbook.
So I have a vlookup function in my final workbook, which lookup for a match in 1st workbook MONTH_DATA and if no match is found there it should lookup next workbook similar to above namely MONTH_DATA2 and continuous till MONTH_DATA6 if no match found till that.

This is what am trying to achieve using my formula

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA2.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA3.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA4.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA5.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA6.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0))))))
```

Actual result: Am getting error messagebox saying, "You have entered too few arguments for this function". I am not getting what I missed

Comment: Your last `IFERROR()` statement contains only one argument where it must contain two.

Comment: Why is the lookup_value the complete column of C? Personally I would de-construct this and test each vlookup separately.

Comment: I don't know the easy ways. Just learning things up 

Comment: SOLVED: Thanks  to @Taosique

Comment: Thanks to @Prima Ananda

Comment: The answer was lying in the comment top ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here :

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA2.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA3.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA4.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA5.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0),iferror(VLOOKUP(C:C,'C:\Users\Sabareesh\Desktop\[MONTH_DATA6.xlsx]day 1'!$B:$C,2,0)))))))
```

u miss 1 arguments like this ')' .
i am try to check your formula here : http://excelformulabeautifier.com/

Comment: It also needs a condition for last IFERROR() as said by Taoshique. In my case I just left the error column as empty by adding a double quotes after first last ')'   `),""))))))`